# Adding an outdoor grill quick-disconnect to my house’s natural gas plumbing

Tags: plumbing, natural-gas

I’ve just been granted a permit by my city to add a 1/2" outdoor quick-disconnect for my grill (and they’ve assured me that I’m allowed to do this as the homeowner). While I’m very comfortable doing electrical work, this will be my first gas plumbing work, and I have several questions I hope someone can help me with.

Below is a photo of the proposed work. There currently exists a 3/4" pipe coming out of the wall to feed the existing tankless water heater (140,000 btu).

[image: Photo showing proposed work.]

My plan (using this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLda3PhR9kQ) as a guide) is to:

1. Add a 3/4" tee between the elbow and flex line to the water heater, a 45° elbow, shutoff valve, pipe, 90° elbow, appropriate reducer, and the quick-disconnect
2. Pressure test
3. Paint
4. Strap this to the stucco

My questions:

1. How do I determine the type of existing pipe? Does it matter, and I mix-and-match metal types? Some fittings are harder to get in certain materials.
2. What’s a good way to stand off from the wall enough to give clearance to work? Threaded rod drilled into the stucco? Some kind of spacer block?
3. Do the connections come loose with force, despite the thread compound on them?
4. Do I just turn off the main gas shutoff and then disassemble the fitting where I want to do the work? Another bit of work I want to do is cap off an interior line intended for a gas dryer (under the house). I assuming opening the pipe down there will release some gas into the crawlspace that I probably don’t want to be breathing.
5. Can I have a single shutoff for both the grill and water heater? Simpler plumbing would be to share the valve for both.
6. Did I miss anything? :)

Comment: Are you allowed to do gas fitting without a license in your city? Issuing you a permit doesn't necessarily mean you are allowed to do the work yourself. Where I live, anyone is permitted to turn off the gas at the meter _in an emergency_, but the gas company would really like to be the ones to turn the gas back on, after inspecting the work.

Comment: I explicitly asked if the homeowner was allowed to do this work, and they said yes. They include a set of points you have to agree to that says you agree to do it to code, etc etc.

Comment: As to point 3, pipe dope actually improves the ability to take apart old pipes that have sat about in the weather, etc, as it keeps the threads from rusting together. It seals, it does not glue or cement.

Comment: It looks like your existing water heater gas connection is missing a drip leg (not an expert).  Your new connection should probably have one too.

Comment: Wouldn't you strap to stucco (with appropriate standoff - maybe plastic block) before pressure testing and painting? I'd be worried about damaging connections with a 3-foot section flopping around unsecured.

Comment: Also, probably not a bad place to bond your cold & hot & gas lines together and to your Electrode Grounding Conductor (electrical panel right there it seems) if you haven't done so elsewhere.

Comment: Another useful gas pipe installation video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5tO-efVZ0Q